# Lean prover: prove existential quantifier by providing an example

Tags: proof, quantifiers, lean

I am a beginner in lean prover and I have struggled a bit with the following example:

I need to proof the following

> ∃ x, f x

Where f is a function defined earlier in the lean file. This seems simple enough and I can easily provide a proof in english (at least I think this is correct):

1. construct an arbitrary y such that f y holds.
2. By constructing an arbitrary y for which f y holds, we have proven the goal ∃ x, f x

However, translating this to lean gives me some problems. I tried using the "let" keyword to construct some arbitrary y for which f holds, but I then am unsure how to use this y to proof my goal

> ∃ x, f x

Is my thinking correct? How do I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Lean, the type `Exists` is defined as an inductive type as below:

```
inductive Exists {α : Sort u} (p : α → Prop) : Prop
| intro (w : α) (h : p w) : Exists
```

So try either writing `refine Exists.intro y _,` (if in tactic mode) or `let y := ... in Exists.intro _` (if in term mode) and seeing what the `_` requires.

Comment: I have done this but now I still have a goal and I don't know how to solve it. I will give a toy example:

lemma testproof : ∃ x : nat, x > 5 := 
  let s : nat := 6 in
  begin
    apply exists.intro s,
    ???
  end 

After the exists.intro, I still have a goal of s > 5 to proof. However, I don't understand this because 6 is clearly greater than 5. In the real example I am facing the goal after the exists intro is a function application of a function whose output will be "true" (after the application). However, I don't know how to proof this goal.

Comment: `dec_trivial` should do the first goal (or `norm_num` if you're using `mathlib`), and `trivial` should solve your real world example (although I can't be sure). The natural number game is good for learning these basic tactics to learn stuff. come join us on the zulip! it's easier to solve issues there: https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using tactic mode:

```
lemma testproof : ∃ x : nat, x > 5 :=
begin
  apply exists.intro 6,
  dec_trivial,
end

#check testproof  -- testproof : ∃ (x : ℕ), x > 5
```

Using Exists directly (with `@` to pass the arguments that would otherwise be inferred):

```
def testproof' := @Exists.intro nat (λ x, x > 5) 6 dec_trivial

#check testproof'  -- testproof' : ∃ (x : ℕ), x > 5
```